# Why zero lccode does not stop hyphenation in LuaTeX?

Tags: luatex, hyphenation, plain-tex

Compile the following example with `tex` and `luatex`:

```
\nopagenumbers
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=0pt
\def\par{\endgraf\hbox to 15em{\hrulefill}}
\hsize=1pt
\hfuzz=15em
1 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious \par
2 s'upercalifragilisticexpialidocious \par
3 supercalifragilisticexpialidociou's \par
4 supercalifragilisticexpialidocious' \par
\end
```

With Plain TeX in case 2) zero `\lccode` stops hyphenation, as it should. Why this is not so in case 3)? How can the rules from *The TeXbook* (page 454) be applied here?

Why with LuaTeX the word is hyphenated in all cases? Besides, in case 2 hyphenation is different from other cases. In which aspects hyphenation in LuaTeX differs from PlainTeX here?

**PlainTeX**
[image: PlainTeX]
**LuaTeX**
[image: LuaTeX]

Comment: For case (3) things are clear enough: TeX90 hyphenates _up to_ the `\lccode` 0 char. The LuaTeX hyphenation approach is entirely different from TeX90 (see the LuaTeX manual), so I don't thin a difference is a surprise.

Comment: The different hyphenation is imho to be expected: upercali... is a different word then supercali.... But I don't know if is it a bug or a feature that luatex `restarts` hyphenation after the quote char. Imho this is a question for the luatex mailing list.

Comment: @Ulrike: feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This old question is still unanswered so I give one for the questions
about plain TeX.

The TeXbook states on page 454:

> TeX looks for potentially hyphenatable words by searching ahead from
>   each glue item that is not in a math formula. The search bypasses
>   characters whose `\lccode` is zero, or ligatures that begin with such
>   characters; it also bypasses whatsits and *implicit kern* items, i.e.,
>   kerns that were inserted by TeX itself because of information stored
>   with the font. If the search finds a character with nonzero `\lccode`,
>   or if it finds a ligature that begins with such a character, that
>   character is called the *starting letter*.

Applied to the four cases the starting letter is always **s**. In case 1
TeX bypasses the right quote.

Next it is explained how TeX finds the end of the word:

> If a suitable starting letter is found, let it be in font f.
>   Hyphenation is abandoned unless the `\hyphenchar` of f is a number
>   between 0 and 255, inclusive. If this test is passed, TeX continues
>   to scan forward until coming to something that's not one of the
>   following three "admissible items": (1) a character in font f whose
>   `\lccode` is nonzero; (2) a ligature formed entirely from characters
>   of type (1); (3) an implicit kern. The first inadmissible item
>   terminates this part of the process; the trial word consists of all
>   the letters found in admissible items. Notice that all of these
>   letters are in font f.

In case 1 the word ends with the blank (all letters are in the same font), so TeX finds the trial word
*supercalifragilisticexpialidocious*. In the second case the right
quote stops the search and the trial word is *s*. Similar, case 3
finds *supercalifragilisticexpialidociou* and case 4
*supercalifragilisticexpialidocious*. Therefore cases 1 and 4 have
identical words.

Then the TeXbook explains that the number of letters in the word must be
at least the sum of `\lefthyphenmin` and `\righthyphenmin` (which is 5
in plain TeX) to hand the word over to the hyphenation
process. Therefore in case 2 no hyphenation is tried.

The rest of the word of case 2 does not qualify for hyphenation as TeX
looks for a starting letter after a glue item. Of course, if
`\hskip0pt` is inserted after the right quote in case 2, i.e.,
`s'\hskip0ptupercalifragilisticexpialidocious \par`, TeX shows the
hyphens it can insert in this rest:
up-er-cal-ifrag-ilis-tic-ex-pi-ali-do-cious. This is identical to the
result that is shown in case 2 for LuaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

LuaTeX has never claimed full back compatibility with TeX and, in particular, its hyphenation algorithm is quite different from the original one.

For instance, TeX never tries hyphenation for character strings that don't follow glue, whereas LuaTeX happily does so.

Similarly, a character with zero `\lccode` ends the word being formed, which will subject to hyphenation; then, after the character, LuaTeX will start forming a new word. If you try

```
\nopagenumbers
\parindent=0pt
\hsize=1pt
\hfuzz=15em

supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious 

\end
```

(yes, without the initial space before the long word) the result will be

[image]

as expected. Or, perhaps, unexpected, depending on your approach. LuaTeX is not the same as TeX in all aspects.